# ARG_SECTION_NUMBER cannot be resolved

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to create 3 different tabs with 3 different fragments for the purpose of having different content for each tab. I'm stuck with some error in my code that says :

> ARG_SECTION_NUMBER cannot be resolved

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Featured", "Browse", "Following" };

private Context context;

public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    //(original coding) return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);

    //getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
    // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(fragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;

        case 1:
            Fragment fragment2 = new DummySectionFragment2();
            Bundle args2 = new Bundle();
            //args2.putInt(fragment2.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 2);
            fragment2.setArguments(args2);
            return fragment2;

        case 2:

            Fragment fragment3 = new DummySectionFragment3();
            Bundle args3 = new Bundle();
            //args3.putInt(fragment3.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 3);
            fragment3.setArguments(args3);
            return fragment3;


        default:
            return null;
    }

}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    //(original coding) return tabTitles[position];

    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return App.getContext().getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return App.getContext().getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return App.getContext().getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
    }
    return null;

}
```

}

Anyone have any idea why ARGS_SECTION_NUMBER cannot be resolved for

- fragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER
- fragment2.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER
- fragment3.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER

The DummySectionFragment.java is as follows:

```
public class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
 * fragment.
 */
public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number_1";
public DummySectionFragment() {

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
    dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
    return rootView;
}
```

}

Comment: Use `DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER` because `ARG_SECTION_NUMBER` is static so no need to use object to access static variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your fragment variable has type Fragment. But constant is defined in DummySectionFragment. So what you need to do is:

```
 args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
```

Remember that when you use constants defined in some class file, there's no need to access them via instance of the class.